# bash: grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2: command not found

Tags: rhel

I'm fairly new to Unix in general and am working on STIG'ing Red Hat 7.

One of the items asks me to check for and set an encrypted root password.

I try to run the command get the following error:

```
grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
bash: grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2: command not found...
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You can see what package provides `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`  using `yum provides \*grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2\*`.  If you want to generate a root password suited for `/etc/shadow` file you can use something like: `python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("mypassword"))'`  and it'll generate a `sha512` encrypted hash

Comment: Tried that command and it said "No matches found".

Comment: Then there is no package available or you need the proper repository. Use the python example if you want to generate the password

Answer (score 1):

Since RHEL7/centOS7 is no longer using grub and instead using grub2, the command is as follows:

```
grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
```

Comment: bash: grub2-mkpasswd-pbkd2: command not found. Any idea which pkg I need to yum in?

Comment: Ah, grub2-setpassword succeeds grub2-mkpasswd-pbkd2